# how to find elements using locators, where multiple elements id or class name is same?

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to finding an element using locators in robot framework, but multiple elements as a same class name and element doesn't have text and resource id. it has Content-desc.
How to get element using Content-desc?

Here what i tried:

```
Click Element  xpath=("//android.widget.ImageView  [contains(@content-desc,'Make an audio call')]")

how to find the element using locator when multiple elements as same class name?
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code that is in your question?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley  i tried above code but i am getting Value error: invalid time string. can you please tell me how to find element using Content-desc

Comment: share HTML structure of elements

Comment: Are you sure _this line_ is giving the error _"invalid time string"_? That's odd, because this line of code doesn't have a time string or anything at all related to time.

Comment: Click Element  xpath=//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc='Make an audio call']     this one is working now.